# fabricjs move cursor at the end of textbox programmatically

Tags: fabricjs

I have a textbox in which I put text content at the time of adding it over canvas and want to make it active. so that user can start writing after the default text added. I have added `enterEditing()` which active textbox but move cursor at the beginning.

```
var object = canvas.getActiveObject('textbox');
canvas.setActiveObject(object);
object.setText("Start");
object.enterEditing();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setSelectionStart(length) and setSelectionEnd(length);` to set the cursor upto the end of the text.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var newText = new fabric.Textbox('Type \n here...', {
  fontSize: 27,
  top: 10,
  left: 10,
  width: 200
});
canvas.add(newText);
canvas.setActiveObject(newText);
newText.enterEditing();
newText.setSelectionStart(newText.text.length);
newText.setSelectionEnd(newText.text.length);
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```